# Object without new operator

Tags: java

```
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

preparedStatement.setString(1, "Gary");
preparedStatement.setString(2, "Larson");
preparedStatement.setLong  (3, 123);
```

'preparedStatement' is an object. But how can we call it as an object if it doesn't use the new operator?

Comment: Actually preparedStatement is a variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure it uses the `new` operator, it just uses `new` somewhere *inside the implementation of `prepareStatement`*.  That's just calling another method that does the `new`ing for you.  That's actually a super common pattern called the *factory pattern.*